# Limit number of words in a cell using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to add a word limit validation to the cells within a column.

For example, I do not want someone to enter more than 150 words.

I wrote a formula to count the words in the cell and tried to add data validation, however it does not work correctly.

Comment: Help us to help you; **post your current code.**

Comment: Data validation should be fine for that. What did you try and what happened?

Comment: From the users' point of view, being rejected after typing >150 words may not come across as an easy-to-use UI; particularly so if they lose their effort.. Why not truncate their input to the first 150 words and possibly even store the rest in a comment?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Worksheet_Change()` event to track changes to a cell and execute some action if some condition is hit:

In VBA, double click the worksheet this cell is in, in the `Project - VBAProjects` pane. Then add this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Target contains the range that triggered this subroutine to fire
    'Lets test it to see if it's the cell we are wanting to track

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        'Cell A1 was changed

        'Shut off events to stay out of endless loops
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        'We can use the Split() function to split the cell into an array
        'using space as a delimiter
        Dim arrWords
        arrWords = Split(Target, " ")

        'Now we can test the size of that array to see if it's more than 150
        If UBound(arrWords) > 150 Then

            'message user
            MsgBox ("You entered more than 150 words into this cell. Try again")

            'Clear the cell
            Target.ClearContents

            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

I would imagine you want to do something more friendly then message them and then dump their hard work into the ether, but this should give you a direction to head.

If you just want to truncate to 150 words instead of clear contents you could use @Jeeped's awesome bit of code:

Instead of

```
 Target.ClearContents
```

Use:

```
 Target.Value = join(split(target, chr(32), 150), chr(32))
```

If you want something smaller that just blindly truncates to 150 words without alerting the user you could do something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Value = Join(Split(Target, Chr(32), 150), Chr(32))
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There is a little used option that can limit the number of array elements returned from a split. I had been thinking about something like  `target = join(split(target, chr(32), 150), chr(32))` ([vba spli](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/split-function))

Comment: Oh. That is nifty. Perhaps just to return back 150 words (truncate instead of clear contents). I will add.

Comment: Nice addition; don't forget to disable events before writing to the worksheet though.

Comment: @Jeeped Added. Thanks for that catch. I have added a tiny version too that uses your 150 element limit to just blindly truncate. That's just the coolest parameter.

Comment: Why not just reset to the previous value with `Application.Undo` instead?

Comment: `Application.Undo` would revert back to previous cell value losing any typing that was done in the cell. Truncating preserves what was typed.

Comment: There's definitely merit in your approach (based on Jeeped's suggestion), provided the user actually typed in 150 words in a cell by hand. However, this sounds more like a copy-paste job to me and hence I think `Application.Undo` makes more sense. This is Excel and not Word after all. But I do get your point.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need VBA to establish a limit to the number of characters in a cell. just go to the validation options in the data tab, select into the allow combo something called text lenght and then put the values limits you need. (i am sorry if i am saying the commands wrong because my excel is in spanish, not english)

Comment: OP wants to limit to a number of words, not characters.